# Missing param even though I can see it IS there

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my params as seem in the rails abort() screen:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"ptXYHkAUh/uvK9blLdcPiarvCYKHJ1HWhqw+dByy7PQ=",
 "account"=>{"name"=>"Hokuriku",
 "amount"=>"0",
 "is_default"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Save",
 "id"=>"5"}
```

See "is_default". But, when I do:

```
def update #accounts controller method
 abort(account_params.inspect);
 .
 .
```

.. in the controller, it only shows:

```
{"name"=>"Hokuriku", "amount"=>"0"}
```

I can't see 'is_default'. Btw this column is also a newly added column. I have migrated though, and I can confirm the new column exists. Also, I've managed to output the value of that column to the the previous screen so I know that the model is handling it.

To fix it, I do the following abort:

```
abort(params[:account][:is_default].inspect); # outputs "1"
```

.. and now I can see it. So it does exist.

Any ideas what could cause this to happen? Ideally I want to handle it in the simplest cleanest way possible, as well as understand exactly what account_params is as it doesn't seem to be the same as params[:account:]. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet that it's the `account_params` method that does the filtering. Whereas in `params[:account]` you access raw unfiltered data.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `account_params` method. It contains a number of instructions to ignore passed params (for security reasons).

It most likely have a form:

```
params.require(:account).permit(:name, :amount)
```

`require` will raise an exception if params do not contain given key and returns matching hash. Permits silently removes all the keys not listed in arguments.

You can read more about strong attributes on github: https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters